# Database connection issue migrating live site to local host

Tags: localhost

Banging my head against the wall for a few days here.  I have a multi site install live and am trying to pull it down to a localhost on my network since the site isn't active and I want to preserve it.  `localhost` is a linux box running 16.04 with:

- `php Version 5.6.29-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1`
- `apache2 2.4.18`
- `mySQL 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16`

The live server is running:
 - `php Version 5.4.29`
 - `mySQL 14.14 Distrib 5.5.52`
 - I cannot figure out how to find out which version of `apache` is running on the live server.

Here's what I have done to migrate:

1. Dumped the `mySQL` database via `cPanel`
2. Installed `mySQL`, `apache2`, etc. on `localhost`
3. Imported the database into `mySQL` on `localhost`
4. Copied *every* file from my live site down to `localhost`
5. Edited `/etc/hosts` to point `127.0.0.1 yyz.com` to maintain the subdomains on the current site.
6. Ran `chgrp` to allow `www-data` to have group access to the folders and files on the local host.
7. Ran `chmod 775` on the folders and files of the localhost
8. Can confirm that localhost is serving `html` and `php` files.
9. Have changed all instances of `wp_*_options` `siteurl` to point to `yyz.com`
10. I have tested the database connection via `php`and it returns proper table counts.  I have done this with a `.php` file served from `yyz.com` (`yyz.com/sql.php`)
11. I have changed the `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD` and `DB_HOST` in `wp-config.php` to reflect a user account that has proper access rights.
12. I have deleted `.htaccess` on `localhost`

When I go to `yyz.com` or `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` I get:

**Error establishing a database connection**

If I go to `yyz.com/wp-admin/` or `localhost/wp-admin/` or `127.0.0.1/wp-admin/` I get:

**One or more database tables are unavailable. The database may need to be repaired.**

If I try to repair the database, I get a number of errors that I do not get if I repair the database on the live site:

```
WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'hack_file' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'blog_charset' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'permalink_structure' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'wp_user_roles' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'template' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'stylesheet' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'category_base' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'tag_base' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'link_manager_enabled' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'sidebars_widgets' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_pages' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_calendar' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_archives' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_links' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_meta' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_search' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_text' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_categories' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_recent-posts' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_recent_entries' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_recent-comments' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_recent_comments' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_rss' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_tag_cloud' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_nav_menu' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'use_smilies' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'cron' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('cron', 'a:2:{i:1484715804;a:1:{s:16:\"wp_version_check\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}}s:7:\"version\";i:2;}', 'yes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('cron', 'a:2:{i:1484715804;a:1:{s:17:\"wp_update_plugins\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}}s:7:\"version\";i:2;}', 'yes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('cron', 'a:2:{i:1484715804;a:1:{s:16:\"wp_update_themes\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}}s:7:\"version\";i:2;}', 'yes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'timezone_string' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'gmt_offset' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('cron', 'a:2:{i:1484768340;a:1:{s:20:\"wp_maybe_auto_update\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}}s:7:\"version\";i:2;}', 'yes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)

WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'theme_switched' LIMIT 1


( ! ) Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/yyz/Applications/yyz/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1220) in /home/yyz/Applications/yyz/wp-admin/maint/repair.php on line 12
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0001  230104  {main}( )   .../repair.php:0
2   0.0289  1714280 header ( )  .../repair.php:12
WordPress database error: [Table 'yyz.wp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'html_type' LIMIT 1
```

Stumped and beyond frustrated at this point.  Any help is appreciated.  Could it be the version differences in `mySQL` or `PHP`?  Those will be hard, if not impossible for me to fix on the `localhost`, since it is using `mySQL` for other applications as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider using migration plugin like All in one wp migration - https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

It takes care of everything out of the box.

Comment: That doesn't work with multisite installs without spending 200 bucks.